# Compactness of operator related to harmonic oscillator hamiltonian

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, quantum-mechanics

Let define the operator
$$A = -\partial_x^2-\partial_y^2+2iy\partial_x+y^2$$
with domain in the Schwartz space of the rapidly decreasing functions. 
Using partial Fourier transform in $x$, the operator can be written as
$$ \tilde{A}=k^2 -\partial^2_y-2yk+y^2=(k-y)^2-\partial_y^2$$
I have to prove that the resolvent operator of $A$ is compact, that is $(A-z)^{-1}$ is compact for some $z\in \rho(A)$. There is an hint to relate $\tilde{A}$ to the hamiltonian of harmonic oscillator and then work on the explicit resolvent (Mehler formula), but I actually don't get it.

Comment: i mean the realtion to the harmonic oscillator is quite clear: the $y$ coordiate is just shifted by the constant $k$

Comment: Yes, that's clear but how do you formalize it? If you change coordinates $x=y-k$ how to deal with the second derivative?

Comment: it should be invariant under a linear transformation, right

Comment: You mean that $\partial_y^2=\partial_x^2$? It doesn't seem so right to me.

Comment: According to the chain rule $\partial_x f(y(x))=\partial_x y \partial_y f(y)$
setting $y=x-k$ and u are done